# ssh porxy with key validation

Tags: networking, ssh

we have so many servers in our company and every time that some one new joins the team
we have to add his/her SSH key to all the nodes and every time he/she leaves we also have to remove that key from all the nodes

i was wondering 
is there a some sort of ssh tool that we can use to act as our access manager?

what i mean is like we create a server which its ssh key is registered in all hosts
and every time that some one enters the company we just add his/her ssh key to that specific server and then every time he/she wants to start a ssh connection to a server , he/she does that by connecting to our access manager and then if his/her key is added to the access managers server , access manager builds a ssh connection to that server and proxy passes the ssh traffic from client to the server

Comment: Instead of just saving shh keys generated in every new connection and saved to ssh configuration files, have you tried using certificates? Sounds like you are interested in something like an authentication server, that acts as a CA (certificate authority) and can also revoke those certificates. Every employee / machine will have their own certificate that can be easily signed and revoked.

Comment: interesting , can you guide me more?
perhaps some links and stuff?

Comment: I'll keep that as a comment because a full answer is going to be too long and still going to lack some information. You will have to do some research about digital certificates in general, and then how to implement such infrastructure in your organisation before starting to implement them on ssh.It could be easy and quick, and could be a bit complex depending on the security level you want to add. But overall if done right, the time spent working on a certificate based system will be easier to maintain and much more secure.

Comment: Some links to get you started: [some basic knowledge about certificates by ssl.com](https://www.ssl.com/faqs) , [Public key certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate).  Implement ssh with certificates: [A good tutorial here](https://smallstep.com/blog/use-ssh-certificates/), [A fully documented Red hat tutorial to OpenSSH with certificate authentication](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-using_openssh_certificate_authentication#sec-Introduction_to_SSH_Certificates). Also good for Ubuntu.

Comment: May be you can solve your problem by "ezafe kardaning Hamed" to your company.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue on your current path you could save a substantial amount of time using Ansible to configure the machines and setup the keys:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/authorized_key_module.html

Ansible is not too hard and has saved us many thousands of hours by templating.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,

even though Ansible is a solution it is not the best one .



lets say if you want to add a new server you should add all of your team's key to that specific server but what i want is to like just add the access manager key to the new server and go (or probably just create a new server from a template which has already has the access managers key in it)